# Wiring of HDMI Extender

Tags: hdmi, bad-wiring

I'm trying to work on a HDMI extender

The purpose is to single out the DDC lines so I can set the default display mode. (plug the male connector into the monitor and the hdmi cable from my laptop into the female port)

I bought two break out boards and was testing the pin outs:
[image]

Both rows of pins match, except the pins connecting to the metal casing are not in the same position.

Using simple jumper cables to connect the matching pins, the extender didn't seem to work when I tested it out (No signals). Could it be I wired the pins wrongly or should I use a properly shielded sets of HDMI cable?

I wired the pins corespondingly: 1 to 1, 2 to 2 etc.

Comment: I don't know what resolutions are you going to use, but HDMI TMDS lines that are used to transfer the picture needs to be a impedance controlled transmission line, and even 1080p signal needs to transfer at a rate of 1.485 Gbps per data pair so random jumper wires might not work even for short lengths.

Comment: @Justme, I'm using 1920x1080. As I replaced the panel, which only supports 59.94 hz, the default refresh rate of 60 hz gave me some issues. Would it be recommended if I solder the jumpter connectors to the shielded cables which I salvaged from some broken hdmi cable and try again? Or should I just remove the jumpers and solder the shielded cables directly to the breakout board?

Comment: I don't see the point at all. 59.94 and 60 Hz are considered identical formats in HDMI, there is no way the display can advertize suppory between those two rates.

Comment: Well, if I don't remotely change the display to 59.94 hz the monitor won't display.
It's pretty finicky.

Comment: What does it mean to remotely change the display to 59.94 Hz? You are using display menus, or PC settings? If you simply need to change EDID then you can enable EDID emulation on the PC.

Comment: then it won't work with the BIOS.